# stocks splitting api google or yahoo

Tags: yahoo-finance, google-finance

I am looking for a way to get stock splitting information. Using the yahoo stock API I can get all types of info on any symbol but I don't think I can get the split ratio or even whether it split. Does anyone know of a way of getting this info?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is how the [quantmod](http://www.quantmod.com/) [R](http://www.r-project.org) package does it.  The split information is in the "Dividend Only" CSV:
http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/x?s=IBM&a=00&b=2&c=1962&d=04&e=25&f=2011&g=v&y=0&z=30000

Comment: How are you deriving split info from the "Dividend Only" CSV?

Comment: Nice, thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for! Where can I get info on all the different search criteria's? I found it on third part website's but nothing official from yahoo. Any thoughts?

Comment: [gummy-stuff](http://www.gummy-stuff.org/Yahoo-data.htm) has the most information.  I think I found the http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/x? URL on the Wealth-Lab forums.  I don't believe Yahoo has any official documentation.

Comment: Also, where else I can find other yahoo URL's for finance. I've used http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=XOM+BBDb.TO+JNJ+MSFT&f=snd1l1yr and now http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/x?s=IBM&a=00&b=2&c=1962&d=04&e=25&f=2011&g=v&y=0&z=30000. Are there other ones? Where can I find this info?

Comment: Sorry, saw your reply after I replied. Thank you.

Comment: is there a way to download all the recent stock splits in one go, rather than stock by stock? thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You can do it easily in python 3 with the help of the pandas datareader package.
Starting defining a function which will return the split history as a dataframe:

```python
def split_history(stock, date_start, date_end, limit_denominator=1000):
    from decimal import Decimal
    from fractions import Fraction
    from pandas_datareader import data as web
    df = web.DataReader(stock, data_source='yahoo-actions', start=date_start, end=date_end)
    is_split = df['action']=='SPLIT'
    df = df[is_split]
    ratios = []
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        # Taking the inverse of the row['value'] as it is Yahoo finance convention
        ratio = Fraction(1/Decimal(row['value'])).limit_denominator(limit_denominator)
        ratios.append("{num} for {denom}".\
                            format(num=ratio.numerator, denom=ratio.denominator))
    df['ratio'] = ratios
    return df
```

Now we can get the splits of Microsoft ('MSFT') as an example:

```py
stock = 'MSFT'
date_start = '1987-01-01'
date_end = '2020-07-22'
split_history(stock, date_start, date_end)
```

```
            action  value       ratio
2003-02-18  SPLIT   0.500000    2 for 1
1999-03-29  SPLIT   0.500000    2 for 1
1998-02-23  SPLIT   0.500000    2 for 1
1996-12-09  SPLIT   0.500000    2 for 1
1994-05-23  SPLIT   0.500000    2 for 1
1992-06-15  SPLIT   0.666667    3 for 2
1991-06-27  SPLIT   0.666667    3 for 2
1990-04-16  SPLIT   0.500000    2 for 1
1987-09-21  SPLIT   0.500000    2 for 1
```

It handles also properly the reverse stock splits:

```py
stock = 'PHM.MC'
split_history(stock, date_start, date_end)
```

```
                action  value   ratio
 2020-07-22     SPLIT   12.0    1 for 12
```

ps: probably there are better ways to input the dates.
ps2: also, the limit_denominator is there to avoid wrong roundings. You can extend it in rare split ratio cases.