# Yahoo Finance API wrong values

Tags: yahoo-finance

I was downloading ( http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=ADS.DE&a=7&b=13&c=2000&d=7&e=14&f=2014&g=d )
the Addidas shares from the yahoo finance site (Symbol "ADS.DE").
And after plotting I compared it with the [boerse.de](http://www.boerse.de/aktien/Adidas/DE000A1EWWW0) graph, but it looks extremely different. For me it is not clear why I get wrong data.

For example in the yahoo finance data on the 05.06.2006 is goes **from  156.00** on the 06.06.2006 **to 38.336**

[image: graph]

Comment: Almost certainly a stock split.

Comment: @PhilipKendall and how to deal with these ? The image looks complete different...

Comment: possible duplicate of [stocks splitting api google or yahoo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119867/stocks-splitting-api-google-or-yahoo)

Comment: @PhilipKendall big thanks, this is a really new area for me. how can i "normalise" the data now ? In my example for ADS.DE there is a Split on the 06.06.2006 with 4:1 . Do i have to divide all later values with 4?

Comment: This is getting very off-topic for SO, but you probably want to divide all *earlier* values by 4.

Comment: My opinion on this is.. all of the stock app used by me keep as it is (some without the connecting line when the "drop" happens). People understand that :)